# Get parent div id of second javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div which is like this:

```
<div id="mainDiv">
<script>
javascript here...
</script>
</div>
```

I basically want to get the ID of the div it is inside.

I have tried using jQuery and classic javascript to do this but it keeps returning undefined.

Does anyone have any idea's? Thanks

Comment: Post the JS you tried that didn't work please.

Comment: Did you try giving an id to the script tag `<script id="foo">`, then `$('#foo').parent()` ?

Comment: Can you post more information? What does the JavaScript contain?

Comment: jQuery selector: `$('#mainDiv');` Why don't you outsource your JS? Please post more code at jsfiddle.net

Comment: $('#script').parent(); did work after setting an ID in the script tag, but unfortunately I can't use it because that script tag is added by an Ajax call each time so it will have the same tags each time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since broswer read the code from up to down, you can do this:

**Vanilla JS**

```
var scriptTags = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var id = scriptTags[scriptTags.length - 1].parentNode.id;
```

**jQuery**

```
var id = $('script').last().parent().prop('id');
```

when it will read this code, the last script tag is the one the browser is reading.

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nb234/

Comment: This is awesome. Nicely done :)

Comment: +1 Good answer that doesn't require him to change anything.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/78N9A/1/

```
<div id="parent">
   <script id="scr">
       function show()
       {
         alert('hello');
       }
    </script>
</div>

window.onload = function(){
    var ele = document.getElementById('scr').parentNode;
    alert(ele.id);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are saying that the id on the parent div is unknown in advance, and you want to use JS to determine what it is.

If you can't edit the script tag to add an id, maybe you could do a `document.write()` within that block to add in a little hidden element, then you can test to see what that element's parent is.

http://jsfiddle.net/AtRYF/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script id="script">
```

Then

```
$('#script').parent();
```

Comment: This did work after setting an ID in the script tag, but unfortunately I can't use it because that script tag is added by an Ajax call each time so it will have the same id each time!

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

    $('div').attr('id');

});
```

should get you the value you need.

Comment: What is `div`, and why are there too many brackets?

Comment: thats a f*** good question ;)

Answer (score 0):

JAVASCRIPT:
Give your script an ID and then use parentNode to move up the DOM.

```
var the_div_you_want = document.getElementById("skript").parentNode.id;
```

JQUERY:
Pretty sure .parent() is what you're after

```
$('#scriptId').parent().attr("id");
```

Regardless, you need to find some way to locate the script and the move up the dom to find that relationship. Hope this helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/Zbuf8/1/